# Attiny88 as I2C gpio expander - analogRead and digitalRead functions do not work

Tags: i2c, attiny

I am working on making a system that has two PCBs mounted atleast 30 cm apart (but not more that 50 cm). The first PCB is the master and the second is the slave, both these have analog and digital IOs. I decided to use an UNO as the master and an ATTINY88 as the slave, and programmed the ATTINY88 as a GPIO, using I2C. I am using [this](https://github.com/jaretburkett/Arduino-I2C-Port-Expander) library to connect to the ATTINY (using I2C) and either write (analog or digital) and read (analog or digital) from various sensors (NTCs, Hall sensors, LEDs or control a DC Motor). I tested this on a breadboard style setup without any issue. I implemented this on a PCB and the analogRead, digitalRead functions dont seem to work. The output is always 0 at the master's serial print. I was wondering if it could be the length of the cable (it is around 35 cm) connecting the master and the slave. It seemed odd to me that I can set pins on the ATTINY using the UNO but never read from it. I tested the breadboard application for almost a month before I got into implementing it on a PCB, and I never found this issue.

I sat in the corner to brainstorm, and came up with a few reasons (I could be totally wrong..):

1. The only difference between the breadboard test setup and the PCB was the length of the cables, maybe the overall I2C bus capacitance is too high?

- How can I check the practical capacitance?

2. Continuing first point: pull-up resistor values are wrong, and is causing some issue(?)

If there was an issue with the capacitance, shouldn't the whole system not work, and why is only the write functions working?

Would be amazing if anyone can help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What value pullup resistors are you using? What speed are you running your I2C bus?

Comment: What happens if you try the long cable with the circuit on the breadboard?

Comment: Modify your software so that the ATTINY88 has some fixed test values which you can query at additional addresses and have your Arduino read those as well as the analog values, that will help you figure out if it is an ADC / analog wiring problem, a software problem, or an I2C one.   Also consider implementing a checksum scheme, or maybe sending both the value and its complement.  Overall your problem here is that you are looking at this as a black box system where all of the parts have to work to get any meaningful result, find ways to test the parts one by one.

Comment: @brhans Im am using 3k3 resistors, I have pull up resistors on both the PCBs (the master and the slave). I am using I2C standard mode.

Comment: @Bruce Abbott, I haven't tried with the longer cables, but I realize now I should try with longer cables, thanks for the idea!

Comment: @ChrisStratton, yes! Great Idea. I modified the firmware at the ATTINY, which will respond with a number when the master requests analogRead (hard coded the number instead of the analogRead), and I still get 0.

With respect to the checksums, I will implement this and see how the system reacts. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you should take a look at the I2C *host* library and learn to distinguish a result from a *read failure*.  You might want to switch back to the breadboard version or shorten the wires momentarily.  Looking with a scope would be good if at all possible.

Comment: I2C "standard mode" does not have a fixed frequency, only a *maximum* frequency. You need to know what yours is set to in your I2C master device in order to determine whether or not slowing it down is likely to make an improvement in your situation. You also should _not_ have pullups on both ends.